# How do I open a wpf window from word using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, office-interop

I am working on a word (2010) addin project. In the ribbon, I have a settings button.

If I click on the settings button, it should open a wpf window (which will have the settings related UI).

How do I open a wpf window from word using C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var window = new System.Windows.Window();
window.Content = new System.Windows.Controls.Button { Content = "Click me!" };
window.Show();
```

You need to reference the following assemblies:

- PresentationCore.dll
- PresentationFramework.dll
- WindowsBase.dll